# Swift 3: add general functions to the whole project, how to?

Tags: ios, function, swift3

I often use functions that simplify the actual functions, like for example the `delayWithSeconds(Int)` for the `DispatchTime.main.asyncAfter(deadline: seconds)`-function. Now, I want to make one Swift file that I can copy into any new project, and use the functions of it in every file of the project. How do I do that and how's the syntax like? When I use extend, I can only use it for one class and not for the whole project.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a file `Utility`(or any other name you like) and paste these lines

```
//Utility.swift
import Foundation

func delay(by delay: DispatchTimeInterval, closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delay, execute: closure)
}
```

No need to write class etc. This function will be globally available to every file.

Comment: Perfect thanks, is it the file name that broadens the scope of the function?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not limiting the scope of the method (either using private or fileprivate), the method will be available in the module to be used.

```
func dispayHighlightedCell(tableView: TableView) {
    ...
}
```

If you want to categorize the utility methods based on the class, you can use extensions as well.

```
extension UITableViewController {
func dispayHighlightedCell(tableView: TableView) {
    ...
}
```